# Is returning different output based on authentication credentials RESTful?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

I have a REST API which allows the developer to fetch a certain resource:

```
/api/projects
/api/project/4
...
```

The API requires authentication. The authentication token is added to the HTTP headers.

Is it RESTful to return a different output based on which user is authenticated?

Thanks!

Comment: As long as the communication is stateless it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST doesn't define anything in that respect.

You should keep authentication logic and authorization logic independent of your RESTful architecture.

There are indeed requirements whereby you want to change what is returned based on different attributes / parameters e.g.:

- authentication type
- time of day
- user location
- device type...

You would achieve that by using a filter in front of your REST service. Filters / interceptors are explained [here](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html).

You would then send an authorization request to a decision point that determines what can be returned based on the identity (or other attributes) of the user.

For instance you could have a logic to return projects to a user if and only if they belong to the same region. The REST endpoint would still be /api/projects but the content returned would differ based on the authZ logic. Have a look at XACML and ALFA to implement that layer.

HTH

Comment: The Jersey library looks very interesting. I started outputting the resources myself with Jackson library, but I will take a look to Jersey first.

Comment: Jackson is only for the json encoding right? Jersey is the rest part